# EXPO AV not playing WAV files on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, mp3, wav

I have an application developed under Expo Go for android and IoS. I have found that the media player I developed using Expo AV will play MP3 and WAV files on android but cannot play the WAV files on iOs.

I could bore everyone with the code - but my first question is: Does Expo AV support WAV files for iOs? Does anyone have an instance of it working?

Thanks